# Creating a new Sharepoint (Office 365) folder

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint-online, mkdir

Using MS Access desktop and trying to create a new sub-folder in Sharepoint (office 365 version) for each record created. Have scoured the web for ideas, tried MkDir, json, and scripting but cannot figure it out. I am sure it must be fairly simple. It works locally to my computer so the issue is me not understanding how to connect to Sharepoint on the cloud. 
Lots of brilliant people out there, any ideas?

Comment: It's not simple at all. Creating a folder on SharePoint is WAY more complicated than just creating one on your own computer. I'm voting to close this as too broad, my personal approach was programming a COM object using CSOM and letting the COM object create the folder, requiring over 100 lines of code.

Comment: Erik thanks for commenting. I looked up CSOM (new to me) and will try to navigate it this way. Once I get closer I might ask for help with details but at least you have given me new path to explore. It appears that you have figured this out.  Too bad it is so hard to find direction when new to programming.  Thanks.

Comment: If you figured out SharePoint authentication (which is very much dependent on your exact setup) and exporting your C# object to a COM object, then importing it in VBA and using it, feel free to contact me (unfortunately you have insufficient rep to chat, so just comment here). At that point I will be able to help effectively.